# scraping price from CSS selector in apify with apify/web-scraper

Tags: apify

starting to use Apify, i was trying to build one simple Actor to scrape price from competitor page that is in CSS
td class="param-value productshipping-param"

i have tried this function already:

```
async function pageFunction(context) {
  const $ = context.jQuery;
  return {
    url: context.request.url,
    value: +$('[class="param-value productshipping-param"]').text().trim(),
  };
}
```

But still i got no results :/

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use class selectors like this:

```
$('.param-value.productshipping-param')
```